# Ruby persistent chat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chat, etherpad

Can anyone recommend a persistent chat plugin for Rails? I'm looking for something close to the persistent chat that is part of [etherpad](http://www.etherpad.org). [Juggernaut](http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/) looks like a possible candidate, but I would like to avoid Flash if I could.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye

Basically you need Socket here (or some imitation). You can use:

- Ajax polling
- Flash socket
- HTML socket

In Rails there is a [juggernaut gem](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut) wich is NOT A FLASH.

Also [Socket.IO](http://socket.io) is very interesting project.